# Nexus read from existing S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, nexus3

My nexus configured to use S3 Bucket as Blob Store.
But the nexus went down. When I created a new nexus server. I would like to use the existing S3 bucket as the Blob Store.

But the new Nexus installation sees it as an empty blob store.

How can I get old data saved in S3 bucket?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to restore S3 bucket blob by running `Create Repair - Reconcile component database from blob store Task`.